# Using Jsoup Elements.select() with Optional.ifPresent

Tags: java, jsoup, option-type

Forgive me for the beginner question. I'm trying to build a web **scraper** . I made a helper class `Selectors` to store CSS selectors of different type and the class has a getter method that returns a optional field value:

```
public Optional<String> getName() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(this.name);
}
```

In my main `Scraper` class I have a method to extract the name from the HTML using the `Selectors` object like this:

```
public String extractName(Element building) {
    if (this.selectors.getName().isPresent()) {
        String cssSelector = this.selectors.getName().get();
        Elements buildingNameElement = building.select(cssSelector);
        return buildingNameElement.text();
    }
    return "N/A";
}
```

As much as I've read this isn't a very nice way to use the `Optional` class. But I'm struggling to come up with a better solution. My first thought was to use the `ifPresent` method but it does not work in this manner:

```
public String extractName(Element building) {
    this.selectors.getName().ifPresent(() -> {
        String cssSelector = this.selectors.getName().get();
        Elements buildingNameElement = building.select(cssSelector);
        return buildingNameElement.text();
    });
    return "N/A";
}
```

I'd like that the `Elements.select()` would execute only if there's a name field present in the `Selectors` object. Could anyone help me make the code a bit more functional?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String extractName(Element building) {
     return this.selectors
             .getName()
             .map(cssSelector -> {
                        Elements buildingNameElement = building.select(cssSelector);
                        return buildingNameElement.text();
                    })
             .orElse("N/A");
}
```

This is what `Optional.map` is for. When you do `return` inside a lambda, you are only returning from the lambda, not from the outer method. So the above uses the text of the building name element if `getName` returned a name/selector. And returns `N/A` if not.

If you’re fine with a more condensed syntax and fewer named variables, you may go with the following:

```
     return this.selectors
             .getName()
             .map(cssSelector -> building.select(cssSelector).text())
             .orElse("N/A");
```

Disclaimer: I haven’t got JSoup on my computer, so I haven’t tested. Please forgive if there’s a typo, and report back.